# Can I change unit response language in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to change the unit responses from English to say....Korean?
The Korean voices just sound honestly *way* better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not directly address an in-game problem.

Comment: @shanodin There seems to be nothing wrong with that request to me. It'll require some modified game files for certain, I don't even know if it's possible at all even, but the question is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/change-your-language) official site, setting your language "pack" can be done in-game.  The fact that they refer to it as a "pack" probably means that changing only the in-game voices is non-trivial.

Looking at this [teamliquid thread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=357930), this guy seems to have had success changing his sound to korean.

Edit:  Reddit page with instructions [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/j1l2p/)